# How to display value on dialog and console in different ways for an object array using paper-check box inside dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

How to display value on dialog and console in different ways for an object array using paper-check box inside dom-repeat

This is the program and How I want the output is mentioned below. Please check the code and help me solve this.

```
Polymer({
    is: 'check-list',
    properties: {
        checkdata: {
            type: Array,
            value: [{
                name: 'Bike',
                no: 1,
            }, {
                name: 'Car',
                no: 2,
            }, {
                name: 'Cycle',
                no: 3,
            }, {
                name: 'Bus',
                no: 4,
            }, {
                name: 'Truck',
                no: 5,
            }],
        },
    },
    checkall: function() {
        var checkvalue = this.checkdata;
            var checktext = [];
            for (i = 0; i < checkvalue.length; i++) {
                var checkarray = {
                    vehiclename:checkvalue[i].name,
                    vehiclenumber:checkvalue[i].no,
                };
                if (checkvalue[i].checked == true) {
                    checktext.push(checkarray);  
                    this.checkeditem = checkarray.vehiclename;
                }
            }
            console.log(checktext);
     });

     <dom-module id="check-list">
         <template>
             <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{checkdata}}">
                 <paper-checkbox on-tap="checkall" checked="{{item.checked}}">{{item.name}}</paper-checkbox>
             </template>
          </template>
     </dom-module>
```

Comment: Want's the output, if checkbox's are checked as
                                                                    
        On-dialog
        Bike, Car, Cycle, Bus, Truck

Comment: Want's the output, if checkbox's are checked as
        
        On-console
        0
        :
        {vehiclename: "Bike", vehiclenumber: 1}
        1
        :
        {vehiclename: "Car", vehiclenumber: 2}
        2
        :
        {vehiclename: "Cycle", vehiclenumber: 3}
        3
        :
        {vehiclename: "Bus", vehiclenumber: 4}
        4
        :
        {vehiclename: "Truck", vehiclenumber: 5}

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to be fixed, just as a starting point, since I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, and what your context is:

- It's necessary to add all values (which you want to be able to bind to in your local DOM, or expose for use in parent elements) to your properties array. I'm not sure about checkedItem, but I added it anyway.
- If you want bindings on your properties to be updated by Polymer, add the `notify` attribute to your property. Also, if you want to notify subproperties on Objects (e.g. `this.checkdata[i].checked`, which is set by the checkbox), you need to define that subproperty on initialization.
- When initializing a property's value with something other than a primitive (i.e. Array or Object), use a function for that; otherwise you'll end up setting the value on your Polymer Object's prototype, which will apply subsequent changes (e.g. Array `push`es) to all instances of your component.
- Use `const`/`let` instead of `var` within a for-loop. Any `var` declaration would be hoisted to the top of your function and closured within any functions defined in the loop's scope, which might lead to unexpected results (though your code would be safe as it is—for the lack of functions—but again, good practice).

I have integrated the above points into your code snippet.

Also, checkeditem is now a bindable/notifying array property, which is appended with each selection. Obviously, you'd have to also *remove* items, whenever its according checkbox is deselected.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'check-list',
  properties: {
    checkdata: {
      type: Array,
      notify: true, // ??
      value: function() {
        return [{
          name: 'Bike',
          no: 1,
          checked: false
        }, {
          name: 'Car',
          no: 2,
          checked: false
        }, {
          name: 'Cycle',
          no: 3,
          checked: false
        }, {
          name: 'Bus',
          no: 4,
          checked: false
        }, {
          name: 'Truck',
          no: 5,
          checked: false
        }];
      }
    },
    checkeditem: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() { return []; },
      notify: true
    }
  },

  checkall: function() {
    const checkvalue = this.checkdata;
    const checktext = [];
    for (i = 0; i < checkvalue.length; i++) {
      const checkarray = {
        vehiclename: checkvalue[i].name,
        vehiclenumber: checkvalue[i].no,
      };
      if (checkvalue[i].checked) {
        checktext.push(checkarray);
        this.push('checkeditem', checkarray.vehiclename);
      }
    }
    console.log(checktext);
  }
});
```

```html
<dom-module id="check-list">
  <template>
      
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{checkdata}}">
          <paper-checkbox on-tap="checkall" checked="{{item.checked}}">[[item.name]]</paper-checkbox>
        </template>

  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: See on dialog box also I have display all the values. If I click on Bike, Car, Cycle. The values must come on dialog as Bike, Car, Cycle. But now what happens is on dialog only the last checked value is displayed.

Comment: There is no dialog box in your code snippet. What do you mean?

Comment: I don't know to chat on stackoverflow

Comment: this.checkeditem is used to display value on dialog box. Sorry i left to add it. I will add now. While running your code on snippet it gives error.

Comment: You're always setting `this.checkeditem` in your loop, so each successive item will override the last one. Perhaps that's the error? Again, there is no dialog, so I don't know which property is bound there, or what other way you're trying to set the value.

Comment: Yeah. There's really no point trying to run isolated code snippets outside of a Polymer context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165278/discussion-between-karthik-and-crapkit).